# CSS3 transform property working differently in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transform

I am using the following CSS to centre a div in the middle of my page:

```
.someWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.centredDiv {
    width: (some width);
    height: (some height)
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I have tested this in Chrome, Firefox and Safari and it works as intended. However, in Internet Explorer (testing on IE11), while it does centre the div in the middle of the window, IE seems to think there is still an invisible 'ghost div' 50% across and 50% down which has not been transformed.

This results in a whole bunch of white overflow space and unnecessary scrollbars in the bottom right corner of the screen. If I turn on overflow: hidden, this can fix the issue, but it is not a feasible option in my website.

So why does IE do this and is there an easy way to get around it?

EDIT: The following code illustrates the problem. Open the code in Chrome or Firefox, there is no overflow. Open it in IE (testing in IE11) and you will see overflow causing white space and scroll bars to the bottom and to the right.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>
     <style>
       html, body {
         height: 100%;
         width: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
       }

       #wrapper {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         position: relative;
       }

       #centred {
         width: 90%;
         height: 90%;
         position: absolute;
         top: 50%;
         left: 50%;
         background-color: red;
         -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       }
     </style>
   </head>
 <body>
   <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="centred">
       Hello world!
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wait. What? Your code works as expected in EVERY browser but IE? GET OUTTA HERE! You MUST be joking ;)

Comment: Amusing, but nonetheless unhelpful...

Comment: @AzzyDude Can you provide a demo of the issue? I work on the Internet Explorer team and would like to look into this more closely. Also, does the issue exist in our [Internet Explorer technical preview](http://remote.modern.ie)?

Comment: @JonathanSampson Hi Jonathan, I have edited my answer and provided an example you can test with. Please let me know if you need any more info!

Comment: @JonathanSampson I just tested it on the technical preview and the abnormality appears there too.

Comment: Thank you, @AzzyDude. I've opened a bug on this and will have the layout team check it out. I have also provided an [alternative approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27022218/54680) below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*Easier Approach*

Instead of positioning from the `top` and `left`, position instead from the `bottom` and `right`. After you've done this, simply change your `-50%` translations to positive `50%`. This will remove the overflow e.g.

```
.center-center {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}
```

You can see these changes in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/bd17gsss/

It's worth noting that this bug is still filed, and our team will still give it the appropriate consideration when time and cycles permit us to do so.

*Original Answer*

There appears to be a layout bug with `position: absolute` in this particular demo. It's behaving similar to `position: relative` when it shouldn't be. I've opened a bug on this issue for the Internet Explorer team to investigate further.

For now, you could switch your position value from `absolute` to `fixed`, which appears to render the centered element correctly. This prevents you from having to use a fixed set of dimensions over and over, and instead allows you to use this approach as a general-purpose `.modal` style class that will center anything it is applied to.

The obvious caveat with this change is that your element is positioned according to the viewport, and no longer the document itself. This will freeze it on the screen effectively.

```css
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

To demonstrate the success this approach has with various dimensions, we can cycle through a few example sets and test the rendering of the element to ensure it is properly centered:

```js
(function () {

    var xandy,
        index = 0,
        modal = document.querySelector( ".modal" ),
        sizes = [
            { x: "50%"  , y: "30%"   },
            { x: "400px", y: "288px" },
            { x: "25vw" , y: "75vh"  },
            { x: "90%"  , y: "90%"   }
        ];

    setInterval(function changeSize () {
        xandy = sizes[ index++ % sizes.length ];
        modal.style.width = xandy.x;
        modal.style.height = xandy.y;
    }, 1000 );

}());
```

The end-result can be viewed online here: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/c00u5ev8/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. Your method relies on me knowing exactly how big the div I want to centre is, and positioning it accordingly. My design is responsive, so the size of the centred div will vary. I would need to use some JS to position it then, which is something I don't have to do with other browsers.

Comment: @AzzyDude The solution above performs identical to the demo code you provided. Two approaches above address relative-sized elements, and absolutely-sized elements.

Comment: OP's "centered" element is neither `90%` nor `850x500` it is dynamic size I think. OP should either use JS or one of your proposed solutions for EACH of his breakpoints I think.

Comment: @ddenhartog The `90%` came directly from the OP's example. You are correct though in that this code would need to be repeated (to some degree) for each media query.

Comment: The 90% came from his faux-code for the purpose of example. His real code doesn't even have valid CSS size attributes. I agree with you though, I think his use of transform is unnecessary.

Comment: What ddenhartog is saying is correct. However, I'm not sure why the transform is unnecessary. With the transform, I do not need to create any media queries. I can centre any sized div in any sized window very easily. Without transform, this requires a lot more code to account for responsive changes in window size and div size. Is this not true?

Comment: @AzzyDude If you want it to work with any element, of any dimension, you could also set its position to `fixed` instead. This positioning doesn't have the layout bug in IE that you found with `absolute`. I've updated my answer with that suggestion, and a quick test to demonstrate its usefulness with elements of varying dimensions.

Comment: Thank you, @JonathanSampson, for doing your best to find a work around. The caveat of the fixed element being frozen on screen is a bit of a headache, but I appreciate your assistance in the matter nonetheless. I think there is enough information here now to close the matter. Any info on the turnaround a bug like this could be fixed in IE though? :)

Comment: @AzzyDude I've already spoken to our lead Layout Program Manager. We're running out of cycles, but I hope to see this get squeezed in since it's a ubiquitous pattern on the web. Watch http://remote.modern.ie for updates.

Comment: @Andrey We've fixed *a lot* of bugs over the past year. This one didn't make the cut, likely because it's not all that hard to work around. Instead of positioning based on `top-left`, position based on `bottom-right`, and then translate `50%` on both axis rather than `-50%`. I'll update my answer above.

Comment: I had a very similar issue on Edge and it was solved with the 'easier' right/bottom approach. Thank you

Comment: IE, when will you finally die...? It seems that IE translates an element but still occupies the original place. "Inverting" the alignment by using bottom and right and negative translates is a very clever ideas. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

If anyone else is still having fun trying to work around this issue (seeing as Internet Explorer bugs never get fixed because we all love having to work around them instead), and you'd like to be able to use `position: relative;` instead of `position: absolute;`, or top and left rather than bottom and right, try this instead:

```
.centredDiv {
    position: relative;
    top: calc(50% - 100vh);
    left: calc(50% - 100vw);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate(100vw, 100vh);
}
```

You can use 100 view height/view width or an arbitrary pixel value representing a maximum theoretical scroll height/width so that the top/left values would never conceivably overflow the parent, and then just offset that in the transform.

---

If I was in an elevator with Hitler, Stalin, and Internet Explorer, and I had a gun with only 1 bullet... I would kill Internet Explorer.

Comment: I think IE's apparent philosophy of "it's not THAT broken, we on't need to fix it", is part of the reason they are the worst and most reviled internet browser.

Answer (score 2):

If actually just answered this very question in another thread, you can use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` to solve this issue (works cross-browser as well!), see my live code here: http://codepen.io/TheDutchCoder/pen/GggWqP

In your case it would be:

```
#wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#centred {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hi, your linked code doesn't appear to be centring the div for me? I just see a yellow square div in the top left corner?

Comment: Does the concept of `tabular data` make any sense to you? What will happen to your element when ***sorting***, ***pagination*** and ***filtering*** will be done by the user, using built-in browser table tools available for `<table>` and `display:table` elements?

Comment: Adding "display: table-cell;" to the div class worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too abbreviated and with no working example it is hard to offer any advice. I am concerned about the `(some dynamic height/width)` part, i.e. this strikes me as a place where your problem could be.

For your reference, you can check out Microsoft's own explanation of [Transform in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127312(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I am using this code in several places where the width and height vary. There is no error in my code. Internet Explorer simply treats the transform property differently to every other browser. It transforms the div, but the space where the div was remains occupied by empty space, creating overflow whitespace.

Comment: Have you tried different versions of `overflow: hidden/etc`?

Comment: Yeah, I cycled through all of them to see if any of them did something useful. Didn't help. I really don't understand why IE choose to be different.

Comment: I have edited my answer with an example you can test with. Try it in Chrome or Firefox, then try it in IE.

Comment: @AzzyDude For the record, we don't *choose* to be different :) Our Layout team works very closely with other vendors to ensure that we aren't different. Browsers are just enormously complicated pieces of software. We'll fix it though, I promise.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue with translate not working in IE 11 was simply that the page was automatically running in compatibility mode, causing IE 11 to run as if it were an older browser, which does not support translate in CSS.

My fix was simply to put this tag in the head:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  ....
```

This tells IE to run in using the "latest" code, which essentially means that IE 11 renders the page with IE 11 code and not as an older version of the browser.

If you want to freeze the compatibility to some specific version of IE you can do that to with this tag, by using different "content" values. The value "IE-Edge" tells it to use the latest code available.

If you want to see if your page is being rendered in compatibility mode, press F12 to bring up Developer Tools in the browser, switch to the "Console" tab, and reload the page. The console tab will say something like:

```
http://yoursite.com is running in Compatibility View because ...
```

if it is indeed running in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `transition: all .2s ease-in-out;` below your transform line.