# Center an overflowing image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an image that overflows on it its parent div, but that's centered according to its parent.

**Heres how I'd like it to look:**

[image]

This is the code I currently have but obviously doesn't work,

```css
.wrapper{
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  margin:5em auto;
}

.image{
  width:175%;
  height:auto;
  position:absolute;
}

body{
  background:purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/goat/goat_PNG13151.png">
</div>
```

**JSFiddle**

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ctrp6hk9/1/)

I want to achieve this in pure css, no use of javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can center your image with the ["negative translate"](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/) trick.

Here's a working example:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  margin: 5em auto;
}

.image {
  width: 175%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

body {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/goat/goat_PNG13151.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: I'd avoid using transform to center content due to issues with IE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000492/css3-transform-property-working-differently-in-internet-explorer
In this use case, it should be fine- though when there are more block level nodes, you will run into some issues with overflowing.

Comment: @Bitz well this is the only way I'd be using it and personally looks like the best way to go about it, or would actually setting top,left,bottom,right to -9999px be a better way..?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it here. The IE "ghost element" issue only typically occurs when using transforms on large or major layout elements - and even then there are workarounds for it. I particularly dislike the `-9999px` solution as it's essentially a magic number (which is a bad thing): https://css-tricks.com/magic-numbers-in-css/

Comment: I would say that it's fine for this use case. @MartijnEbbens, and as Jon points out- the other solutions rely on magic numbers to deal with a less than ideal situation. If you were to continue to build with this, you may run into some funky layout issues later on. Hard to say exactly what though. (Overflowing things like this tend to not play nice with inline block level elements)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562457/center-oversized-image-in-div).

```
.wrapper{
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  margin:5em auto;
}

.image{
  width:175%;
  height:auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  margin: auto;
}

body{
  background:purple;
}
```

Comment: This works altough I'd more satisfied with the way of @Jon Uleis since I feel like using a negative of 9999 doesn't really seem the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.image{
  width:175%;
  height:auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  margin: auto;    
}
```

It should center your `<img>` no matter the size of the parent `div`

Answer (score 0):

Oh looks like I'm late to this party, but I was going to suggest this technique - using the `::after` pseudo element to draw your square underlay and don't actually make the image overflow the wrapper div.

https://codepen.io/hamzatayeb/pen/QMxJvw

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/goat/goat_PNG13151.png">
</div>
```

Then this CSS -

```
.wrapper {
  width: 262px;
  height: 262px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5em auto;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16%; right: 16%; bottom: 16%; left: 16%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.image {
  padding-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

body {
  background: purple;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this add this style only to your image

```
.image{
      width:175%;
      height:auto;
      position:absolute;
      top: -18px;
      right: -65px;
 }
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sikandar_ali_akram/ctrp6hk9/6/)